# the download of an xml.gzip file does not work

Tags: javascript, angular, download

I will download a xml.gzip File with the Response:

Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate

Connection: keep-alive

Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=ERKENNUNGSMODELL_CI.9.221_part_1_of_1.xml

Content-Encoding: gzip

Content-Length: 1323

Content-MD5: fIHw5FJ1KWkBHsZ+jbkuwg==

Content-Type: application/xml

Date: Thu, 10 Sep 2020 07:56:46 GMT

Expires: 0

Keep-Alive: timeout=60

Pragma: no-cache

Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains

X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

My Code is:

```
download(url) {
let downloadHeaders = new HttpHeaders({ 'content-type': 'application/xml; charset=UTF-8',
  'authorization': "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem('token') });
downloadHeaders.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
this.httpClient.get('/rest/ui/download/product-part/' + url, { headers: downloadHeaders }).subscribe(response => {
    console.log(response);
    this.downLoadFile(response, "application/xml");
  }
);
```

}

```
  downLoadFile(data: any, type: string) {
let blob = new Blob([data], { type: type});
let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
let pwa = window.open(url);
if (!pwa || pwa.closed || typeof pwa.closed == 'undefined') {
  alert( 'Please disable your Pop-up blocker and try again.');
}
```

}

With
new HttpHeaders({ 'content-type': 'application/xml; charset=UTF-8', 'authorization': "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem('token') });

In console.log the file is displayed correctly. but the download does not work: Http failure during parsing for "myUrl"

Comment: Try to add `responseType: 'blob'` like this `... {headers: {...}, responseType: 'blob'} ...` when u call .get

Comment: thanks. the blob opens a new window. how i can download the content as a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned before you have to add `reponseType: 'blob'` to your get options.

This how I handle it in one of my applications, where `const data` is the blob returned from `downloadAttachment`. It is probably not the cleanest way to do it, but it works.

```
  async downloadAttachment(id: number, filename: string) {
    const data = await this.front.downloadAttachment(id);
    const downloadURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.target = '_blank';
    link.href = downloadURL;
    link.download = filename;
    link.click();
  }
```

Check if it helps. If you have any questions, just ask here.